# How much ground truth is needed for a classification model?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, accuracy

I have unstructured problem text that needs to be classified into categories(Multinomial classification).  Depending on the component, which is a structured element that allows me to segment the data, the number of categories per component can vary from 5 to 35.  The volume of problems per component can range from 200 to 1200 per month.

Component A might have 5 categories and 400 problems per month and Component B might have 25 categories and 1000 problems per month.

I am trying to establish guidance/methodology/formula on how many problems needs to be judged in ground truth to measure model accuracy.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't think this is answerable because it doesn't depend on the number, it depends how easily the classifier can distinguish the categories. There might be some problems which need only 10 instances, and some for which an infinity would not be enough. Of course it will also depend on the level of imbalance: when the number of categories is high it's likely that some categories have very few instances, perhaps not enough for a representative sample.